# Join lines into one line using awk

Tags: awk

I have a file with the following records

```
ABC
BCD
CDE
EFG
```

I would like to convert this into

```
'ABC','BCD','CDE','EFG'
```

I attempted to attack this problem using Awk in the following way:

```
awk '/START/{if (x)print x;x="";next}{x=(!x)?$0:x","$0;}END{print x;}'
```

but I obtain not what I expected:

```
ABC,BCD,CDE,EFG
```

Are there any suggestions on how we can achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to SO, edited your capital letters subject to proper one.

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following.

```
awk -v s1="'" 'BEGIN{OFS=","} {val=val?val OFS s1 $0 s1:s1 $0 s1} END{print val}' Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
'ABC','BCD','CDE','EFG'
```

Comment: `val=val?val OFS s1 $0 s1:s1 $0 s1` = `val=(val ? val OFS : "")  s1 $0 s1`. Improved clarity and less redundancy and improved robustness across all awks since it parenthesizes the ternary expression.

Comment: @Vikakmis, you could select any of the answer as correct answer too, to close the loop properly.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
$ awk -v RS='\n$' -F'\n' -v OFS="','" -v q="'" '{$1=$1; print q $0 q}' file
'ABC','BCD','CDE','EFG'
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways of achieving this:

**with pipes:**

```
sed "s/.*/'&'/" <file> | paste -sd,
awk '{print '"'"'$0'"'"'}' <file> | paste -sd,
```

*remark:* we do not make use of `tr` here as this would lead to an extra `,` at the end.

**reading the full file into memory:**

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/'"','"'/g;s/.*/'"'&'"'/g' <file>  #POSIX
sed -z 's/^\|\n$/'"'"'/g;s/\n/'"','"'/g;' <file>      #GNU
```

and the solution of [@EdMorton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52205262/8344060)

**without reading the full file into memory:**

```
awk '{printf (NR>1?",":"")"\047"$0"\047"}' <file>
```

and some random other attempts:

```
awk '(NR-1){s=s","}{s=s"\047"$0"\047"}END{print s}' <file>
awk 'BEGIN{printf s="\047";ORS=s","s}(NR>1){print t}{t=$0}END{ORS=s;print t} <file>
```

**So what is going on with the OP's attempts?**

Writing down the OP's awk line, we have

```
/START/{if (x)print x;x="";next}
{x=(!x)?$0:x","$0;}
END{print x;}
```

What does this do? Let us analyze step by step:

- **`/START/{if (x)print x;x="";next}`::** This reads *If the current record/line contains the string `START`, then do*

  - `if (x) print x`:: if `x` is not an empty string, print the value of x
  - `x=""` set `x` to be an empty string
  - `next`:: skip to the next record/line

  In this code block, the OP probably assumed that `/START/` means *do this at the beginning of all things*. In awk, this is however written as `BEGIN` and since in the beginning, all variables are empty strings or zero, the if statement is not executed by default. This block could be replaced by:

  ```
  BEGIN{x=""}
  ```

  But again, this is not needed and thus one can remove it:
- **`{x=(!x)?$0:x","$0;}`::** concatenate the string with the correct delimiter. This is good, especially due to the usage of the ternary operator. Sadly the delimiter is set to `,` and not `','` which in awk is best written as `\047,\047`. So the line could read:

  ```
  {x=(!x)?$0:x"\047,\047"$0;}
  ```

  This line, can be written shorter if you realize that `x` could be an empty string. For an empty string, `x=$0` is equivalent to `x=x $0` and all you want to do is add a separator which all or not could be an empty string. So you can write this as

  ```
  {x= x ((!x)?"":"\047,\047") $0}
  ```

  or inverting the logic to get rid of some more characters:

  ```
  {x=x(x?"\047,\047":"")$0}
  ```

  one could even write

  ```
  {x=x(x?"\047,\047":x)$0}
  ```

  but this is not optimal as it needs to read what is the memory of `x` again. However, this form can be used to finally optimize it to (per [@EdMorton's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52204214/join-lines-into-one-line-using-awk/52205336?noredirect=1#comment91363858_52205336))

  ```
  {x=(x?x"\047,\047":"")$0}
  ```

  This is better as it removes an extra concatenation operator.
- **`END{print x}`::** Here the OP prints the result. This, however, will miss the final single-quotes at the beginning and end of the string, so they could be added

  ```
  END{print "\047" x "\047"}
  ```

So the corrected version of the OP's code would read:

```
awk '{x=(x?x"\047,\047":"")$0}END{print "\047" x "\047"}'
```

Answer (score 0):

`awk` may be better

```
awk '{printf fmt,$1}' fmt="'%s'\n" file | paste -sd, -

'ABC','BCD','CDE','EFG'
```

Comment: Instead of specifying the format in a variable assigned outside of the script you can just use `awk '{printf "\047%s\047\n", $1}'`

Comment: Thank you very much for the helpful tip @Ed Morton :)